# Variable not getting set correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I'm having a problem:  Variable `output` doesn't change the way it should.
When logging it inside the `while` loop it's being edited in it shows up fine.
But when logging it again outside the loop the change never happened.

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
  var foot, fs, head, inputFile, output, outputFile;

  fs = require('fs');

  head = "var setStyles = function(){";

  foot = "}";

  inputFile = "css/index.css";

  outputFile = "compiled/index.js";

  output = head;

  fs.readFile(inputFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var css, identifier, match, prop, regex, results, selector, styleMatch, styleRegex, styles, tag, val;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    css = data;
    regex = /(\.|#)?([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)\n*{([\s\S]+?)}/;
    results = [];
    while (match = css.match(regex)) {
      identifier = match[1];
      tag = match[2];
      styles = match[3];
      if (identifier === ".") {
        selector = "document.getElementsByClassName(" + tag + ");";
      } else if (identifier === "#") {
        selector = "document.getElementById(" + tag + ")";
      } else {
        selector = "document.getElementsByTagName(" + tag + ")";
      }
      output = "";
      styleRegex = /([a-zA-Z-_]+?):\s*(["'#-_a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\s*;/;
      while (styleMatch = styles.match(styleRegex)) {
        prop = styleMatch[1];
        val = styleMatch[2];
        styles = styles.replace(styleMatch[0], "");
      }
      results.push(css = css.replace(match[0], ""));
    }
    return results;
  });

  console.log(output);

  output += "\n" + foot;

  fs.writeFile(outputFile, output, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });

}).call(this);
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
Jordy

Comment: `readFile` is an async function, so you need to do everything inside a callback. You can use the `sync` version of the function if want to

Comment: Isn't the whole thing inside it's callback?

Comment: @g3mini Nope, the callback ends with `return results; });`. [`readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) may be your best bet.

Comment: You guys rock! I put the `writeFile` inside the callback and it works now =)

Comment: Should I just put everything in the callback as is right now, or use `readFileSync`?

Comment: generally in javascript use asynchronous code when you can. So I would recommend the callback.

Comment: @g3mini your `return results` won't return anything to the calling code anyway, so you can go with async version

Comment: Alright, thanks both! :D